# Joomla 3 Media Manager creating all new subfolders and uploaded files into the top level images directory

Tags: php, joomla

I am building a Joomla site and the media manager is having some problems.  I can't create subfolders or upload images into subfolders in the media manager.  I can navigate into subfolders and see their files, but if I create a new folder or upload a new file it ends up in the /images directory.

I have noticed that in the links the url queries included &folder=  with no value.  Looked into the php files and saw that $this->state->folder returns an empty string even when in a subfolder.

Anybody else having this problem and know a solution?

Edit: latest version of Joomla (3.3).  Also should mention this problem is only happening in the default media manager.  If I use JCK manager built in with my editor there are no problems.

Comment: Any updates on default media manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They fixed the problem: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3575/files

All you need to do is go to: administrator/components/com_media/views/media/tmpl/default.php line 72, and change

```
72: <input type="text" id="folderpath" readonly="readonly" />
```

to

```
72: <input type="text" id="folderpath" readonly="readonly" class="update-folder" />
```

go to: media/media/js/mediamanager.js line 45 and change

```
45: this.updatepaths.each(function(path){ path.value =folder; });
...
48: this.updatepaths.each(function(path){ path.value = ''; });
```

to

```
45: this.updatepaths.each(function(path, el){ el.value =folder; });
...
48: this.updatepaths.each(function(path, el){ el.value = ''; });
```

GL

Answer (score 2):

I made these edits - and checked against the same amendments in Github ... but I still get the same problem/error.

Even without this particular problem, I find that the RH pane often doesn't display the contents if you use the "up level" icon to go up the hierarchy. I can *eventually* force it to display by operating only in the LH "tree" menu.

Media Manager has always been the "Achilles Heel" of the Joomla admin interface. I could use much stronger language ... but it really needs to be sorted out. Yes, as Superadmin I also have my own FTP access, but my clients/co-admins don't (and shouldn't) have this option.

Also - how on earth do you copy or move an image from one folder to another?

Media Manager hardly "manages" at all IMHO. It's a joke.

Answer (score 0):

Download JCE, it comes with a JCE File Browser that does the job.

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/editor/joomla-3